# picture is not loaded when choosing combo values

Tags: excel, vba

I work with a combobox and an image control.
what should I do to link combo values to image pictures.

```
With Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value
    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "liberty s 50"
            Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("D:\Afshar\programming\PIAGGIO\LIBERTY S 50.jpg")
    End Select
End With
```

No error appears. Image control show nothing

Comment: In which procedure did you put this code?

Comment: Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Comment: is the line `Me.Image1.Picture = …` executed at all? Put a `Stop` as first statement in your `ComboBox1_Change` so the code stops there in debug mode and then go through your code step by step using F8 check the value of the `ComboBox1.Value` variable then and see which steps of your code run and which not. Note that `With Sheet1.ComboBox1.Value` does't make any sense at all (you can remove the `With` statement completely).

Comment: Danke schon. It worked.